# Cross platform Qt project does not compile on windows because of errors in ostream and qiodevice.h

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++-2010

I have started a cross platform desktop project ussing Qt on my MAC and compiles fine.
Now, I am trying to compile the same project on a Windows 7 PC with Visual Studio 2010 installed but I am getting some strange errors in two files out of my project. Here is a screenshot of the errors when I click on build:
[image]

and this one:
[image]

How can I fix these build issues?

Comment: I am running Qt Creator 3.2.1 (opensource)

Comment: It says macro 'write' is defined somewhere

Comment: As kotlomoy says, there seems to be a macro named `write` causing havok (also a macro named `close`, and I'd guess others that might be causing conflicts). Depending on how the`write` macro is defined, you might get the compiler to tell you where that's happening by passing `/Dwrite=xyzzy` on the compiler command line options.

Comment: @kotlomoy Yes, I had a "send" defined as "write" for sockets portability between mac and windows builds. I removed that line and the errors are gone. Can you post your reply as an answer so I can accept it? Thank you.

Comment: @Michael Thank you Michael, that was it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says macro 'write' is defined somewhere

Answer (score 0):

in your code instead of using `qint64`
use `qintptr`